# FBJS security weaknesses

Tags: security, fbjs

Someone recently told my coworker that our site is relatively insecure from an FBJS standpoint.

Since I wasn't there at the time, I wasn't able to ask why.

What are some factors that influence the security of an FBJS implementation?

Thanks very much,

Michael

Comment: By FBJS are you talking about Facebook JavaScript?

Comment: Yes -- http://wiki.developers.facebook.com/index.php/FBJS